# Is it possible to add required parameter for Floating action button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

If you see some E-commerce apps it prompts a size or color required to be selected ,if you click on add to cart button without selecting a color or size .When the user clicks on add to cart button i want a required parameter, where the user should select a size and only  then the function in onPressed should work. .How do i add that required parameter with FloatingActionButton?

Comment: please share what you've been attempting so far, and also try to make the question more objective. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Then you can use an expanded Floating action button which displays the size and on clicking the size it can add the item to cart. Or else you can have a dialog box to select the size and after that, it can be added to cart.